# PySpark - List created in dataframe column is of type String instead of Integer

Tags: python, list, pyspark

I have a dataframe -

```
values = [('A',8),('B',7)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2'])
df.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   A|   8|
|   B|   7|
+----+----+
```

I want the `list` of **even numbers** from 0 till `col2`.

```
#Returns even numbers
def make_list(col):
    return list(map(int,[x for x in range(col+1) if x % 2 == 0]))
make_list = udf(make_list)

df = df.withColumn('list',make_list(col('col2')))
df.show()
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|           list|
+----+----+---------------+
|   A|   8|[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]|
|   B|   7|   [0, 2, 4, 6]|
+----+----+---------------+
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- list: string (nullable = true)
```

I get the list I want, but the list is of `string` type rather than `int`, as you can see in the `printschema` above.

How can I get the `list` of `int` type? Without `int` type, I cannot `explode` this dataframe.

Any ideas as to how can I get a `list` of `integers`?

Comment: If you don't specify the return type of the `udf`, it will default to `StringType`

Comment: By the way, if your end goal is to `explode` the list, you can also try a variation of the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

Comment: Thank you so much Pault for your efforts. I will explore the link. I asked this question as I wanted to solve this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320724/pyspark-split-interval-into-sub-intervals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the return type of the `udf`; to get a `list` of `int`, use `ArrayType(IntegerType())`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

# specify the return type as ArrayType(IntegerType())
make_list_udf = udf(make_list, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df = df.withColumn('list',make_list_udf(col('col2')))
df.show()
+----+----+------------+                                                        
|col1|col2|        list|
+----+----+------------+
|   A|   6|[0, 2, 4, 6]|
|   B|   7|[0, 2, 4, 6]|
+----+----+------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Or if you are using spark 2.4, you can use the new `sequence` function:

```
values = [('A',8),('B',7)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import sequence, lit, col
df.withColumn('list', sequence(lit(0), col('col2'), step=lit(2))).show()
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|           list|
+----+----+---------------+
|   A|   8|[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]|
|   B|   7|   [0, 2, 4, 6]|
+----+----+---------------+
```

Comment: I have some thoughts on how to do this using only the API functions, but in this case I think the `udf` is preferred.

Comment: Feel free to post an API version if you have one in mind though; It may not be what OP is asking for but can still help -

Comment: actually I found a reasonable way without a `udf`

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, there is a [closed form function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*sum%5Bi*10%5E%5Bn-i%5D%5D+from+i%3D1+to+n) that will get the number that is represented by joining the digits in your desired `list` column.

We can implement this function and then use some string manipulation and regular expressions to get the desired output using only the API functions. Even though it's more complicated, this *should* still be faster than using a `udf`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def getEvenNumList(x):
    n = f.floor(x/2)
    return f.split(
        f.concat(
            f.lit("0,"), 
            f.regexp_replace(
                (2./81.*(-9*n+f.pow(10, (n+1))-10)).cast('int').cast('string'), 
                r"(?<=\d)(?=\d)", 
                ","
            )
        ),
        ","
    ).cast("array<int>")

df = df.withColumn("list", getEvenNumList(f.col("col2")))
df.show()
#+----+----+---------------+
#|col1|col2|           list|
#+----+----+---------------+
#|   A|   8|[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]|
#|   B|   7|   [0, 2, 4, 6]|
#+----+----+---------------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
# |-- list: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

**Explanation**

The number of elements in your desired list is one plus the floor of `col2` divided by 2. (The plus 1 is for the leading `0`). Ignore the `0` for now and let `n` be the floor of `col2` divided by 2.

If you joined the numbers in your list together (as you can using `str.join`), the resulting number would be given by the expression:

```
2*sum(i*10**(n-i) for i in range(1,n+1))
```

Using Wolfram Alpha, you can compute a closed form equation for this sum.

Once you have that number, you can convert it into a string add in the leading 0.

Finally I added in a comma as a separator between each of the digits, split the result, and casted it into an array of integers.

Comment: I have to say this is really smart. It's going to take people some time to digest though. In spark 2.4, you can actually use `sequence` to do this to avoid `udf`. Nonetheless a good solution before spark 2.4.

Comment: @Psidom actually this breaks when `n>4`. `sequence` is the optimal solution for 2.4+, otherwise use a `udf`